# Having trouble displaying data from sql database to PDF

Tags: java, itext

When I run this code, it generates the PDF, although only the brand will be displayed and not the cost. It seems it only displays Strings and not integers, floats etc.. and if I was to create a table and use `.addCell(temptr.getFltTyreCost());` not only it doesn't work, but I get an error

> not suitable method found for addCell(float).

Code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TyreTread2013DTAPU");

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

List<Tyrerange> tr = em.createNamedQuery("Tyrerange.findAll").getResultList();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(tireFile));
document.open();

Image ttlogo = Image.getInstance(ttLogo);
ttlogo.scaleAbsolute(525, 85);
document.add(ttlogo);

document.add(new Paragraph("Inventory Tire Stock on Hand Report",
        FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC, 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED)));
document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
document.add(new Paragraph(" "));

document.add(new Paragraph("Brand \t\t Cost"));

for (Tyrerange temptr : tr) {
    document.add(new Paragraph(temptr.getStrTyreBrand()));
    document.add(new Paragraph(temptr.getFltTyreCost()));
}
```

Comment: Where do you have problem in the code you share?In **temptr.getFltTyreCost()** ?

Comment: Yep, temptr.getStrTyreBrand() displays the brands in the pdf. But temptr.getFltTyreCost() doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

I assume in your line

```
document.add(new Paragraph(temptr.getFltTyreCost()));
```

you want add a new paragraph which contains a textual representation of the float returned by `temptr.getFltTyreCost`. Unfortunately the Paragraph constructor with a float argument does not interpret the float as something to display but as leading:

```
/**
 * Constructs a <CODE>Paragraph</CODE> with a certain leading.
 *
 * @param   leading     the leading
 */
public Paragraph(float leading)
```

Thus, you first have to convert your float to string, e.g.:

```
document.add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(temptr.getFltTyreCost())));
```

Comment: Hehe thanks, i worked it out before looking here :) but yup it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @hadsi if mkl got the answer right, please award the points for the answer.